# Question about finding the sum of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm really stuck with my homework in real analysis. Could anyone give me some ideas/tips or solutions, how to get these following tasks done? I would be very thankful!

> We have a series
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x^k(1-x) $$

The following tasks are need to be done for this series:
1) Find the sum of the series $S(x)$.
2) Does this series uniformly converge to a sum $S(x)$ in $[0,1)$.

Comment: Just use the typical geometric sum formula. You can expand it first to see it as a subtraction of two GP's.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the partial sums.

$\begin{array}\\
s_n(x)
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n} x^k(1-x)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n} (x^k-x^{k+1})\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n} x^k-\sum_{k=2}^nx^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n} x^k-\sum_{k=3}^{n+1}x^{k}\\
&=x^2-x^{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

These converge if
$-1 < x \le 1$
and diverge otherwise.

If $-1 < x < 1$
the sum is $x^2$.
If $x = 1$
the sum is $0$
(which is obvious from the definition
since each term is then $0$).